# I'm really cold and my heating is broken! Please write a rust or python program that will heat my laptop up

Tags: code-golf, optimization

I'm working from home and the heat of my laptop on my lap is the only thing keeping me warm. I have a Dell G3 Laptop with an NVidia GEForce GTX CPU.

I have tried writing a rust program with 5 threads that calculates and prints the Fibonacci sequence in an infinite unthrottled loop, but that only gave a bit of warmth, and eventually gave an overflow panic. I've tried running the `ai_benchmark` python module benchmarks in a loop but that was even worse. Using pip to download tensorflow has given me the most warmth so far for some reason.

The winner will be the warmest program, or in case of a draw, the shortest warmest program. The deadline is 30 minutes. I'm cold!

Comment: What's the power rating of your power supply?

Comment: I believe you may want a coffee delivery software instead. ;)

Comment: What exactly are you asking us to do here?

Comment: This needs a lot more clarification on what the winning criteria actually is. I suggest posting to the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main

Comment: Search for more terms in any OEIS sequence with keyword "more". That will keep you warm for many years...

Comment: @Blue7 I can program you an electronic heater, a heat-up device can pollute environment and your PC health...